# How can I get rid of select input border

Tags: html, css

[image: Select with Border]

How do I get rid of that white background behind the image?

CSS:I thought webkit would do the trick but it's not

```
 <style>
 .qq {
    background-image: url('../images/select-category.png');
    width: 148px;
    height:34px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
  }
 </style>
```

HTML:

```
 <div style="float:left;">
      <form>
          <select id="basic" class="qq" onchange="showFolders(this.value)">
              <?php
                  foreach ($folder as $t)
                  {
                      echo '<option value="'.$t['folder_id'].'">'.$t['name'].'</option>';
                  }
              ?>  
          </select>
      </form>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That white background is *probably* present in your image file select-category.png.  To remove it, you will need to edit the image file itself.

If not, then it's coming from *somewhere else*.  Please provide a small self-contained example, which contains just enough code to demonstrate the problem, without anything extra. Post this code into the question, or in a JSFiddle (jsfiddle.net). Be sure that this example hast HTML (not PHP) and contains your image file.

Comment: You were right on..when I opened the image on my mac in preview it took off the transparent borders, but they show-up on the web. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The only problem i can think of is your image at the other hand you can try

```
    img{
       background-color:transparent;
       border:none;
    }
```

*and to make a pure css3 button http://www.cssbuttongenerator.com/*